# Difference between "needed" and "necessary"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between those two words?

Example sentence: "this can greatly reduce the **needed** | **necessary** effort". I found some posts saying that necessary is more urgent?! Are there more differences?

Comment: I noticed you haven't joined [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) yet. Perhaps that's not necessary, but I think this question might be better over there. Also, whether you ask here or there, it's always a good idea to include some dictionary definitions when you're asking about the difference between two words. That accomplishes two things: (1) it lets everyone know that you've done your own investigating, and (2) it alleviates the need for everyone else to perform the task of looking these words up, which is the natural place to start when answering such questions.

Comment: @J.R. thank you for pointing me to ELL! I will incorporate some definitions!

Comment: Even before looking up the words you've highlighted, you might consider re-wording the sentence:  This [procedure] can reduce greatly the effort required.

Comment: I don't think urgency has anything to do with the issue. Neither word imolies anything either way about urgency.

Comment: I need a good stiff drink, but, I'll admit, it's not really necessary for my existence.

Answer (score 9):

> 1. The spelling:

*Needed*
*Necessary*

> 2. Part of speech:

*[Needed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/needed)*: past participle form of verb *need*; sometimes uses substantively as a noun.
*[Necessary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/necessary)*: an adjective.

> 3. *Necessary* is the *[idiomatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20needed%20effort%2C%20the%20necessary%20effort&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20needed%20effort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20necessary%20effort%3B%2Cc0)* choice--13 times more common than *needed* in the OP expression:

[image]

> 4. Oxford Dictionaries Online recommends *necessary* in lieu of *[needed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/needed?searchDictCode=english)*.

Answer (score 1):

The word "needed" sees most of its use as the past tense of the verb "to need". Due to its repeated glottal stops, it has the tendency to appear clumsy when employed as an adjective, which is why the word "necessary" has become so common. Compare the frequency with which one encounters the word "desired", as opposed to "desiderated".